# Vuejs with jQuery autoNumeric or number plugin - only data in list (v-for) are formatted

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Please I have been trying to fix this for the past 48hrs but still no luck. I am using the jquery autoNumeric/numeric plugin to format numbers so it's comma separated. I have been doing this with jQuery alone and it has been working fine. I am new to Vue so when I used it with vue, I get it to start working after I initialized it within the **update() **  function. But something happened, I have this following model:
 `{'success':1,totalIncome:49000,data:{[{'name':'john','income':'200'},{'name':'Sam','income':'500'}]}`

And my html:

```
<div id="app">
     <span v-for="item in model.data">{{item.income}}</span>
     <span>{{model.totalIncome}}</span>
</div>
```

And in my vue root instance within the updated hook, I initialized autoNumeric as:

```
Updated:function() {
      $('span'). autoNumeric('init') ;
}
```

But from the result, only those **span** tags within *v-for* directives were formatted, the other **span** tag was not. Please I need help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What "other" span tag? Please put all relevant code in your question.

Comment: That model can't be right. `data:{[{'name':'john','income':'200'},{'name':'Sam','income':'500'}]}` is not valid javascript.

Comment: There are two span tags above, one with v-for directive and the other containing {{model.totalIncome}}. The later is not updated.

Comment: @Bert oh my bad data:{'success':1,totalIncome:49000,data:{'model':[{'name':'john','income':'200'},{'name':'Sam','income':'500'}]}

Comment: Do you use autonumeric for inputs? For formatting input values as you type? Or you use it only for output, as in your provided code?

Comment: @WaldemarIce exactly for formatting output

Comment: @Ezugudor OK, so look for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

for output use filters. [vue2-filters](https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters) makes it easy

import:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'

Vue.use(Vue2Filters)
```

Usage:

```
{{ amount | currency }} // 12345 => $12,345.00
```

Use a different symbol:

```
{{ amount | currency('£') }} // 12345 => £12,345.00
```

Use a different number decimal places:

```
{{ amount | currency('₽', 0) }} // 12345 => ₽12,345
```

---

The problem with mixing jquery and vue is that they may be fighting each other to update the components. Consider sticking with Vue only as much as you can.

instead, use a vue version of the plugin from: 
https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric

Comment: Thanks Daniel but vue-autoNumeric is strictly for input tags, but my case is different as mine are span tags. Please am used to jQuery but I fell in love with vue because of its templating style. I was using Handlebars before now but prefer vues method of listing (v-for within tags and supports expressions) . Please if I can get a templating engine like that I wouldn't mind dropping vue because I have really spent time on this little issue and wud not like to repeat same again. Please. Thanks in advance

Comment: as mentioned in other answer/replies. If using for output only, try a library that is meant for output. Vue has a filter function for this kind of stuff, and there are filter libraries out there already that make this really easy, such as https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters

Comment: @Ezugudor well, `vue-autoNumeric` will soon™ allow you to use other tags supported by the `AutoNumeric` library, not just the `<input>` one, so that's a good news, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use autonumeric for output. Its primary purpose is formatting input, not output. And it is slightly outdated. And vue-autonumeric is also for inputs. Do not use them.

For formatting output use accounting.js (http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/). It is far better choice for your purpose. It is actual, tiny, standalone library. And do not use the updated hook, use filters instead.

Definition:

```
// This is global filter for all components,
// but you can define filters in components also
Vue.filter('euroFormat', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return accounting.formatMoney(value, "€", 2, ".", ",")
})
```

Usage:

```
<!-- Min version from CDN -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/accounting@0.4.1/accounting.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-for="item in model.data>
    {{ item.income | euroFormat }}
  </span>
  {{ model.totalIncome | euroFormat }}
</div>
```

Done. It is really simple like that.

PS: And if you need to format input value as you type, it is simple also:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    income: ''
  },
  filters: {
    formatted (value) {
      if (!value) return ''
      return accounting.formatMoney(value, "€", 2, ".", ",")
    }
  }
})
```

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="income">
  <p>Your income is <span v-cloak>{{ income | formatted }}</span></p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/accounting@0.4.1/accounting.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeeeaaahhhhh!!!! ...it's now working... Tanks guys... God bless you @Waldemarlce you really saved me alot of stress and further frustrations :) thanks for the accounting.js it's just priceless. And Tanx for exposing me to filters... never knew wat that dude does :). I appreciate

Comment: Hey guys, full disclosure here, I'm the AutoNumeric owner, and I have a few comments. First, AutoNumeric can indeed perfectly be used as an output-only library (even in web workers!) by using the static `AutoNumeric.format()` or `AutoNumeric.unformat()` functions (or [more](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/next#static-methods)). Second, how is it *slightly outdated*? What makes you say that? the jQuery dependency has been nuked, it's written in pure ES6, etc. I'm always eager to improve the library, so please tell me :)